# What is the fastest way to send file over serial console?

Tags: linux, python, serial-port

I have to write a binary file to an embedded device over a UART console. I know about SLIP, PPP and ZModem, but the device has a minimal busybox and no way to install additional services or programs.

I am currently using the Python serial library to write hex-escaped bytes to the device:

```
printf '\x00\x01\x02' >> file.bin
```

Because of the large file size, I can't print the entire file at once, as it exceeds the write buffer size, so I have to do it in chunks. It seems that I also have to read the output of the console after every write (the feedback of my entered command), otherwise the buffer gets full again (not sure if this is because of the Python serial library or because of the device).

All of this results in having to write more than 4 times the file size, as well as reading the same number of bytes in order to successfully transfer my file. This is obviously very slow and inefficient.

Is there any other method I could use to transfer a binary file faster under these circumstances ?

Comment: Does [this method](http://k.japko.eu/serial-transfers.html) work?

Comment: As I'm dealing with binary files, I would have to use the busybox uuencode method. As I said previously, the device has a minimal busybox, so it doesn't have this functionality. There is also the serio Python script, which does exactly what I'm doing, but without reading from the device after writing, which results in transferring ~ 5000 bytes out of 64000. Neither of those methods work.

Comment: So your busybox doesn't have `busybox rx`? The xmodem protocol used by `rx` should also deal with binary files.

Comment: Yes, it does not have buxybox rx. I am also trying to develop my Python script as a general tool that works on most, if not all devices. So for this purpose I am assuming the device will have only a minimal busybox installed, like the one I'm testing my script on.

Comment: If this is an exercise in "use only stuff that's installed on my machine to make transfer efficient" it's going to be difficult to answer without knowing what exactly is installed on your machine, if it doesn't even have the usual busybox commands.

Answer (score -1):

Busybox normally contains awk. If you have that you are in luck.
On the source, use base64 to encode the file, and then cat it into xclip to put it on the clipboard:

```
cat file.bin | base64 > file.bin.base64
cat file.bin.base64 | xclip -sel clip
```

On the target, you need to cat stdin to a file:

```
cat - > file.bin.base64
```

When the serial console stops scrolling, press Ctrl-D to terminate the stream.

Then you'll need a [base64 decoder written in awk](https://github.com/shane-kerr/AWK-base64decode/blob/master/base64decode.awk).

vim that into a file, save it, and use it to decode the base64 encoded file you transferred.

That's the distilled diet version. Here is a more end-to-end complete article on how to [paste copy a file over bare serial console](https://shatteredsilicon.net/transfer-file-over-serial-console/).

Disclosure: I wrote the referenced article.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)